# View technologies for a spring mvc web application

Tags: view, presentation

I'm developping a web application with Spring MVC, and I'm totally new in web design I want to write my `Views`, but i don't really know how to design all of that, I need about two views, One form for an advanced search for items, and the other for viewing results.

is there any framework or facilities that i can begin with ?

I've skimed view Technologies part in the spring documentation, I found:

1. JSP/JSTL
2. Tiles
3. Velocity & Freemaker
4. XSLT

Is that all i can use ? which one you recommand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mostly used view implementation (which also has best tool support) is JSP/JSTL.

From the Velocity/Freemarker family (sort of) you can look at [ThymeLeaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org) - it's clean and really easy to learn. It also gives you ability to use *natural templating* - HTML files which, without changes, work in web application (as SpringMVC views) and when opened directly in browser.